# Resizing GridLayout area

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, grid-layout

I have a 4x4 gridlayout and I'm trying to add 2 title bars above the tables I've created. I'm creating panels for title bars but because of the gridlayout it fills up all the space. Here's the code:

```
private WebScrollPane createPosRiskPanelWindow(int w, int h) 
{
    //Content area
    posRiskPanel = new WebPanel((new GridLayout(2,2)));
    posRiskPanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    //Add title bars
    WebPanel posTitle = new WebPanel(new WebLabel("Current Positions"));
    posRiskPanel.add(posTitle);

    WebPanel riskTitle = new WebPanel(new WebLabel("Risk Exposure"));
    posRiskPanel.add(riskTitle);

    //Panels
    CreatePositionPanel(posRiskPanel);
    CreateRiskParamsPanel(posRiskPanel);

    //Scroll content
    posRiskScroll = new WebScrollPane (posRiskPanel, false);
    posRiskScroll.setPreferredSize (new Dimension (w, h));

    return posRiskScroll;
}
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]
Is there a way I can resize those top 2 boxes?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use GridLayout for the overall layout, since the only thing it knows to do is to create cells that are all exactly the same size. Since you don't want this, your GUI will require a different layout. Instead use GridBagLayout or else you could use nested JPanels with differing layouts, but I think that GridBagLayout for the overall layout is likely your best bet here. Other considerations include MigLayout if you're willing to use a 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to just put the tables in their own panel and a titled border like so:

[image]